# how to update value from sequelize and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

For some reason I can't seem to be able to update a property object after a `.find()` in sequelize and node.js.

for example

```
const user = User.findAll({where: { categoryId: 1 }, include: categoriesUser });
```

data for user is

```
 user = {
    name: 'test',
    categories: [
     {
       id: 'name',
     }
    ]
  }
```

Data is good so i want to do the following

```
const new_cat = [
 { 
   id: 'name',
   status: 'true'
 }

user.categories = new_cat 

return user
```

for some reason user data still unchanged, I can however change the data for primitive data type but I can't change the data for reference type such an array or object

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think this may be just a JS syntax problem, please could you post your code exactely as it is (at least the relevant part) ? (The returning function, where you update the object and where you can see that the updating didn't work)